# ¿Qué palíndromos existen que sean realmente largos?

Tags: palabras-raras, curiosidades

Un [***palíndromo***](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/palindromo) es:

> Palabra o expresión que es igual si se lee de izquierda a derecha que
>   de derecha a izquierda.

Me preguntaba, por curiosidad y a modo de "competición" entre las respuestas, quién conoce el más largo (que tenga sentido).

Comment: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capicúa

Comment: @WalterMitty buenas walter, capicúa me temo que es únicamente para números. Saludos !

Comment: Así es.  Pero entre los niños en Argentina, se acostumbraba llamar los palindromos capicúas.

Comment: Buscas palabras o frases? Las frases me parecen un poco [off topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `Preguntas sobre "listas", donde cada respuesta es igualmente válida.`

Answer (score 11):

**30 caracteres**

La ruta nos aportó otro paso natural.

Answer (score 9):

Según la Wikipedia en su artículo [Palíndromo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal%C3%ADndromo#En_espa%C3%B1ol), existen muchos y algunos bastante largos:

#### 291 caracteres

> Adivina ya te opina, ya ni miles origina, ya ni cetro me domina, ya ni monarcas, a repaso ni mulato carreta, acaso nicotina, ya ni cita vecino, anima cocina, pedazo gallina, cedazo terso nos retoza de canilla goza, de pánico camina, ónice vaticina, ya ni tocino saca, a terracota luminosa pera, sacra nómina y ánimo de mortecina, ya ni giros elimina, ya ni poeta, ya ni vida (de Ricardo Ochoa).

#### 115 caracteres

> Allí por la tropa portado, traído a ese paraje de maniobras, una tipa como capitán usar boina me dejara, pese a odiar toda tropa por tal ropilla (de Luis Torrent).

Comment: El de 291 caracteres no parece tener mucho sentido, pero quién sabe, igual es que no tengo el nivel suficiente para entenderlo. :-D

Comment: Como bien alguien escribió en la Wikipedia: "*Habitualmente, las frases palindrómicas se resienten en su significado cuanto más largas son*".

Answer (score 6):

#### Ana

> Ana fue eso: pétalo anual.
> La yerba es amor
> a leal dama así;
> rima y oda mayor.
> Al caminar es imán.
> Ana mi ser anima
> claro y amado.
> (Ya, mi risa: ¡amadla!)
> El aroma se abre, y allá,
> una ola te posee ufana.

Autor: Francisco Rendón Ramos.

Answer (score 5):

### 25 caracteres

Un clásico:

> Dábale arroz a la zorra el abad.

Answer (score 3):

With enclitics

- **12 letras:** [sonetéetenos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YMJg1pm)<sup>1</sup>

Sans enclitics

- **10 letras:** [somarramos](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=somarrar)
- **9 letras:** [abatataba](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=abatatar), [sometemos](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=someter), [reconocer](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=reconocer), [sereseres](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xf0BzPR), [sanidinas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XDnRETh)

Special mention to the nearly palindromic [*dadivosidad*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dadivosidad).

---

<sup>1. [*242.242 Palíndromos Españoles*](http://www.carbajo.net/varios/pal.html), Víctor Carbajo (2022)</sup>

Comment: No me convence Víctor Carbajo con eso de "sonetéetenos". "Sonetee" está en tercera persona, "te" en segunda persona y "nos" en primera persona. "Sonetear" es un verbo intransitivo y no puede tener todos esos enclíticos en distintas personas.

Answer (score 2):

Prefiero los palíndromos más cortos, pero que tengan sentido y una mínima consistencia ortográfica y gramatical. Ejemplos:

> Anita lava la tina.

También este otro:

> Se es o no se es

Answer (score 1):

El ávido lo copa o coplero podía. Habla o recita y arma más a cada día. Sé amor y si es amor breve sale todo tan en su bonita parte para la mirada de los otros y os adula ser amadas, o la más lene Eva y Sara dan el bondadoso don a seres ropones y odiosos. Ulises ilusos eran agrios. Ana, Sarita, Lara, con ávida, loca soledad, Eva, Elsa, la otra, Petra, son amigas. La fácil o cubana Sarita se va, aparta a ralea con otro Basilio. Seis son, amas a mares o niña, dama, mala, rota, sosa, mona. Tigres y osos residen, opacos unos, a la caza rota de la madona y otros balan alegres. Las amadas nacen en las áridas, urales rocas. Una es la rusa. Mira por deparar y añadir, a poco la liga o ya la cala, Deseona, Zola te raje. Rosa es o la lámina la mate. Moló a nazi uranio. Rehusó rimel en odioso ojo. La mejor raza para amar os aleja tobas, os ama sin evasivas. Amor baboso si es, no será hoy amor. Al edénico da sana para platónico tema. A sur, arte plácido nada modelado. La morita Lara se aboca, da de si, mas, ese ave acá lo palió y la separó, sanó mis y a ti. Ve edad, Ivana, su samaritana, eleva los senos. Ana ropa saca. Manolo cede. Le dice: de ducales amores, adoro poder, nena, ser imán agorero. Toro tasado y ahora corneado es el erigido como el ajado. No, as, o no, don, usó rey. Era honor tapadura osada. O dote dar o dale ver. Ya se pisan. Rut con nata daré dopada. Delo solo. Sal, nene me trae son Amaral y sol racionado. Petra no conoce sol y oír folía con Ígor, opina negadora, negada, marearte sólo y abuso. Ese da loca cocaína, Mor toda soledad. Ese ver y no ser es odio. Ojo, cae fatal oro. Moda dopa. Oí, limé. No cocina. Tasó, tirad obús, no reíd, ruso dará. Cansen Alí. Vagón o rail al son. Una bala calaba son. A grosero metió sola. Mojón. Esa más leo y acoso de imitadas aperturas o no menos eróticas. Ira malévola, Tamara, la mala, a los osados atacó, pero no. Elsa, marido soso, gujo, copón y soso tite, pasó, ni vida. Nos asola, las odas. A ser, a mal, acosó Ra, sol y zorra o sorba, sepa ganar garbos el amo. Toma, madre imana gas. Oí, le da, dale, no tracé pro y amo rol o dorar ropa. Nacarado tío, con si es o no esa, ellas ya valen oro, caladas. Epopeya roja barata. Oírle. Ana es oleaje del ocaso, catalana, sane heredera. Hoy no, maja. Mírela, va dotada, toda varada, la liga abajo, Manolo ídem y a tálamo tiraron el pavor acalorado. Romana vino, milanesa oí. Reseña bemol, epidemia samosatena. Sola colará pieles o rasurará perras. Apática se es. Es oído. No repares. Oí. Domó consumo, ni moderado ni sacro. Lo dominará desde rabo a cabo. Soñáramos, a la nevera, mosaico, columna. Sí. Ugalde decoró mínimos. A pare mujer, es la Elsa más leal, la Sara mira la mar. Además, ellas, en el orbe le comerán el leve llano del ocioso varón etéreo, roedor y amargado paladín. A sor, gen. Oso irás, oso ve, lanar es. Eres sol, el ademán oso sí va a delataros, o dirá: otra harina, moler anima. Caminará seguro de su sabático natural. Nenas osan unísonas. Ellos les adornan, unos la cara, pero dan otros a lugares, o casi pululan en asedio sin un ápice más amigo. Caramelo y agrio le dieron y supo mal. Asumiré hoy, no sólo di ahora, todo ese deterioro. Mala dio su persona. Rime rotas a parábolas enanas y si nuera, ésa, anula lo rico, no conoce seco refrán, a galeras a remar, a remar a galeras, a toro y yermos son rey y oro. Tasar él a Gara, mera ramera. Sar, él a ganar feroces. Eco, no conocí rol. A luna asearé. Unís y sanan. Ésa loba rapas. Atore. Míranos, repuso, id al amor. Oiré, te deseo dotar. O ha ido. Lo son. Yo herí musa, lamo pus y no reíd. El oír. Gay, ole. Mar, acogí masa, mecí pan. Unís, oíd esa nena. Lulú pisa. Coserá gula, sor, tonado repara cal. Son. Unan Rodas. El sol le sanó. Sin unas, osan. En la ruta no citabas. Usé do. Ruge sar, anima caminar. El Omán irá harto. Áridos, o rata le da aviso. Son amé, dale. Los seres eran alevosos, arios o negros. Anídala, poda grama y rodé o roeré. Tenor, a vos oí, colé. Dona. Lleve. Llena remo. Celebro, lene, sal, lesa me da rama. La rimará. Sal. La Elsa más leal, seré jumera; pasó mini moro. Ceded. La guisan, mulo cocí. Asomaré. Ven al asomar año. Soba caoba, red. Sé dar ánimo, dolor casi no daré. Dominó mus, no, como Dios era, pero no Dios. ése. Esa cita: pasar, reparar, usar, osé, leí, para loca lo sané. Tasó masái, medí pelo, me bañé, sé río. A Sena, limón. Iván amó rodar o lacar. O va pleno, rarito mal ata y me dio lona. Mojaba, a Gila la dará. Va dotada toda. Vale, rima jamón. Yo haré de rehén, as. Anal, ata cosaco, le deja él, ose Ana, el río atar abajo, raye Po. Pesada la colore, lava y sal le aseó, no seis, no coito da arcana, por raro dolor o mayor pecar. Tonelada de liosa gana. Mierda mamó, toma, le sobra. Gran ágape, sabroso arroz y los aros o calamares asados a la losa. Son a divinos, apetitosos y no poco jugosos, o dirá más Leonor. Época tasó. Das, o sola, a la mala rama talo vela. Marisa citó. Resonémonos. A Rut repasad. A ti, miedoso, cayó Elsa, mas, enojó. Malos oí, temores. Órganos a bala calaban. Unos la liaron, o gavilanes nacarados urdieron su boda, rito satánico, con Emilio, apodado moro, lata fea, cojo. Oído seré. Son y revés, edad. Él. Osad, otro maníaco caco la deseó. Suba. Yo lo sé traer. Amada, Genaro da gen. Ani, por Ogino caí, lo frío y lo seco no, con arte podan. Oí Carlos y Lara manosear. Temen en la, solo soledad, apoderada, tan nocturna, si pesa y reveladora de todo. Adas o a ruda, patrono haré y Eros, uno, donosa o no, da jaleo. Moco di, gírele, sé oda, en roca, roha y odas, a toro, torero gana. Mire, san enredo, por oda ser o más él acude. Decide, le dé Colón. Ama casa por Ana. Sones, sola ve, lea Nati. Rama, su sana vida. De Evita y Simón aso rape, sal y oí. La polaca Eva es esa, mis edad, a coba, esa rala. Tiro malo dale, domada. No di cal. Petra, rusa, ame tocino tal para pan asado. Cine, del aroma yo haré. Son seis, o soba bromas, avisa, venís. Amaso sabotaje. La sor ama a rapaz. Arroje. Mal ojo os oí. Doné. Le miró su heroína, Ruiz. Ana, o lo meta mal. Anímala. Lo seas. Oreja reta Lozano. Ese da la cala. Yo, ágil a loco parí, daña y rara, Pedro parí. Más ural. Sean. Usa corsé. La rusa dirá: sal nene. Cansa dama. Sal. Ser gel anal, absorto, ya no. Dama le dató raza cala. Son usó Capone. Di. Ser soso y ser gitano más os atora la mama. Dañino será, mas, ámanos si es. Oí lis. Abortó, no cae, Lara atrapa aves a tiras, Ana, bucólica, falsa. Giman. Osar. Te parto alas. Lea, ve, da de losa, cola. Di vano. Cara, la tira sanas. Oír ganar. Esos Ulises ilusos oí. Doy seno, por ser esa, no, dos, o dad noble. Nadarás. Ya ve en Elsa. Malos adamaré. Saluda, soy sor. Toso. Le da. Da rima Lara, Petra, patinó bus, nena, todo. Te la se ver, broma. Seis y Roma es. Aída da casa. Mamá y a ti, cero. Alba ha ido por él. Poco a poco lo di. Vale .

Comment: Superlargo, pero creo que un poco más carente de sentido que los otros. No solo son frases inconexas, sino que algunas carcen casi de sentido. "Ulises ilusos eran agrios; Dama le dató raza cala; Anal, ata cosaco, le deja él, ose Ana, el río atar abajo, raye Po". Otros, como la respuesta Hugo Casanova, por lo menos tienen valor poético. Este es genial a nivel técnico. La parte de "que tenga sentido" (que pide la pregunta) pues queda un poco en el aire.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un libro llamado *Simetral artemis* (un corto palíndromo) escrito por Juan Pablo Saéz Gil, de 6886 palabras, el cual es un palíndromo completo. Aunque no lo he leído, en tal caso sería uno de los palíndromos más largos existentes. Te sugiero en el sitio del [Club palindromista internacional](https://cpalindromistai.blogspot.com/), para buscar un poco más del tema

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo un palíndromo pero no es largo es normal.

"Yo hable a María y Airam a Elba hoy".

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo otro palindromo:

> Sola va a dia dia aida ida avalos